# When checking if value is selected from dropdownlist it exits the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a checkbox and a dropdownlist and I am trying to check that if the checkbox is ticked, a value has been selected from the dropdownlist. That works fine but if the alert message pops up and I click OK to remove the message, it exits out of the page I was in. I want to say on the page same, I don't know why it is redirecting me somewhere else. Also if possible I would prefer if the error message `ErrorMessage = "Please select"` appeared instead of the alert box but that isn't the main issue here.

```
    <tr>
                                                    <td class="Header">License Type</td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlHazLicenseType" CausesValidation="true" >
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                        <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
                                                              ControlToValidate = "ddlHazLicenseType"
                                                              ErrorMessage = "Please select"
                                                              ValidateEmptyText="True"
                                                              ClientValidationFunction="validateHazLicenceType" > 
                                                        </asp:CustomValidator>                                                    
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr> 

function validateHazLicenceType()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=chkHazTrained.ClientID %>").checked) 
        {
            var ddl = document.getElementById("ddlHazLicenseType");
            var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
            if ($("#ddlHazLicenseType")[0].selectedIndex <= 0)
                {
                    alert("Please select a licence type");
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you could post more of the page's markup? It's hard to to tell if you are posting-back or submitting, using an UpdatePanel, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
function validateHazLicenceType(oSrc, args) {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=chkHazTrained.ClientID %>").checked) {
            var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=ddlHazLicenseType.ClientID %>");
            if (ddl.selectedIndex <= 0) {
                args.IsValid = false
            }
        }
    }
```

`CausesValidation="true"` seems to only cause validation when the selected index changes - which means if the initial selection is index 0, and the user never changes it, it won't validate as intended. You could try setting the DDL's selected index to -1 (so nothing is selected), but I don't think that solves the problem. You'll probably have to validate the DDL value somewhere else - on submission, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I last worked with asp, and it would be nice to see the actual source (html) code. Anyway, 2 things come to mind:

1) Have your validation js function return false at the end
what happens is your validation function assumes the validation passed, and submits right after that. Returning false would prevent that to happen ( good thing to know on the side: return false means you stop the default action and stops event propagation)

2) Your submit onchange for the DDL may be somehow turned on